# How to find which direction to flow between two points in QGIS Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, pyqgis-3, pyqt4

I want to find which way direction to go based on two points and line segment.
I have two layer line layer and point layer.user selects the two points in lines layer.
I have to find which direction to go from first point to second point based on line segments to collect intermediate points.

All the lines in line layer is breaked every point to point.I want only one direction .

I have already tried create the buffer for first point to get inital two lines and loop through direction left or right until second point found. It takes more time.

How can I do that?

[image].